# Copying specific data from Access into specific fields on Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

The people I work for have asked me to change up the order system they currently have in place as it is quite old and they want to update.
So I have moved the table to Excel like they have asked so that it does not sit on the order form but they also want it so that when they click on the "Trade Account" button on the Excel form it opens a Query in Access (Which is all done) that asks them to enter in the account information (company name). When that is done it will bring up all the account information for them to see, now this is where I am stuck. They would like me to make it so that the information that comes up is copied into the trade account fields in the Excel document so that they do not have to spend time typing it out by hand and I currently have no idea how to do this as I do not have experience using VBA on here. (Probably sounds dumb but i'm trying to learn)

I can also provide images if that would explain it better.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea, moving to-and-fro between Access and Excel. Execl is good at displaying queries, results, creating nice pivot tables and charts. But if you want to edit the data, stick to Access. Can't you stay in Access, use forms and queries?

Comment: What I'm saying here is you might be a lot better off with a full redesign. Rethink this whole thing, lay out the full process, and design your solution from the ground up. You will learn more from it, it will be faster and easier to maintain.

Comment: Maybe I can try and talk to the boss when he comes back from Spain and see what he says. If hes does it will be fine because I am more than capable to set up Access. Thank you for helping (I don't know why people downvote me :( )

Comment: Another issue I have found is that the people I am doing this for don't have much experience with Access (Although I can easily set up tool tips) so maybe they will be a little sceptical about moving such important things?

Comment: You have a better chance with the boss if you already have some kind of plan. Think it through carefully, collect some questions about the process and usage, and maybe come up with an estimation.

Comment: If you create a good tool in Access, they won't even have to realize it is Access. (I thought you said it already was in Access, or at least partly.) About the down vote: StackOverflow is a site for straightforward programming questions. Yours is just too general I guess. But you also got an up vote, so opinions might differ. It is not a reflection on your personality, don't take it yo your heart. :)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Its sorta hard because it's my first time doing this kind of thing for a company and it's quite intimidating (its lots of important data such as accounts and sales that I am playing with)

Comment: Yeah... Backup. Like, a lot. And work on an offline copy.

Comment: And oh ok I will try and be more straightforward. Yes I do have the accounts on there its just the rest such as the current orders etc. I'm hoping it goes well because I am enjoying the experience :') I should be able to take a copy from the network to play with so if it does go wrong I don't trash it all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered your other question with a different solution.  Here is another way to do what you want, using a Query.  This is nice because you can control the query like a filter, and import the results from that object.

```
' Set a reference to DAO 6.0

    Sub GetQuery()
        Dim dbs As DAO.Database
        Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
        Dim i As Long
        Dim wsh As Worksheet
        Set dbs = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\your_path\Northwind.mdb")
        Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Invoices")
        Set wsh = Worksheets("Sheet3")
        For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
            wsh.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rst.Fields(i).Name
        Next
        wsh.Range("A1").Resize(ColumnSize:=rst.Fields.Count).Font.Bold = True
        wsh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
        rst.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
        dbs.Close
        Set dbs = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: So i followed this method but for some reason I get the error "User defined type not defined" Im not too sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you set a reference to DAO?  Alt+F11 > Tools > References > Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library

Comment: Now I have a new question, when I go to run it I get told there are too few parameters and that is expects one, the problem being is that the query is there so that the user can search for a company such as "Bristol Airport". Im not really sure what it means as my criteria is "Enter Company Name"

Comment: I did fix some of it but yeah the error still stands

Comment: perhaps I could send a screenshot somehow

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do this.  Here is one.

I am using the Northwind Database!

With the following vector in Sheet1:

```
10248
10249
10250
10251
10252
```

Run the following script, in Excel, and the results will be copied into Sheet2.  Oh, don't forget to set a reference to Microsoft ADO 2.8!!

```
'Set db = ws.OpenDatabase("C:\your_path\Northwind.mdb")

Sub DAOParamTest()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MyCell As Range


''Access database

strFile = "C:\your_path\Northwind.mdb"

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

'Rough idea
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

For Each MyCell In rRng
intID = MyCell

    strSQL = "SELECT * " _
           & "FROM [Order Details] " _
           & "WHERE OrderID = " & intID

    rs.Open strSQL, cn
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close

Next MyCell

''Tidy up
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is yet another solution for you to consider.

http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbadacimportado

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!